# Laravel get result of each return QueryBuilder fields

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

i want to get all row by `all()` and into foreach i want to get fields of other table in query builder.

```
$getResult = webLinks::all();

$result = array();

foreach ($getResult as $value) 
{
   $query = DB::table('webInformation')
            ->where('webLink', '=', $value->id)
            ->get();
    $r['site']  = $value->webLink;
    $r['webLink']  = $query->webLink; //I GET ERROR                 
    $result[] = $r;
}
```

in this coomand i can not save `webLink` of `webInformation` table into array.

i'm try this:

```
$r['webLink']  = $query->webLink;
```

or

```
$r['webLink']  = $query['webLink'];
```

how to fix this problem?

Result of that :

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [webLink] => 1
            [updated_at] => 2014-03-13 10:20:16
            [created_at] => 2014-03-13 10:20:16
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [webLink] => 1
            [updated_at] => 2014-03-13 10:25:32
            [created_at] => 2014-03-13 10:25:32
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`->get()` returns an `array` of all hits found. If you only want the first result you can use `->first()` instead.

```
foreach ($getResult as $value) 
{
   $query = DB::table('webInformation')
            ->where('webLink', '=', $value->id)
            ->first();
    $r['site']  = $value->webLink;
    $r['webLink']  = $query->webLink;            
    $result[] = $r;
}
```